# Java 8 - POST request with Bearer token fails with 401

Tags: post, java-8, bearer-token, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

Please note that I must use java 8 for this work.
Initially do a POST for authentication to the middleware Gateway and  get **accessToken**. Using the same access token I do a POST to the service end point url. I set all the required headers in request properties but I get 401 in response. I am trying to not use any external libraries and trying to do this is pure java. Any help appreciated.

Exact error I get is {"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "token not found, expired or invalid", .....}
As you can see below I am setting access token, is there something else missing in this code?
Below is the code:

```
 private static void sendPOST(){
    String jsonStr = getPostDataJson();     
    InputStream stream = null;      
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    if(accessToken != null && accessToken.length()>0) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(jsonStr.length()));
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");              
            conn.setUseCaches(false);               
            conn.connect();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(jsonStr);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Status Code :" + responseCode);     
            
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                stream = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Post request encountered error." + responseCode);
            }
        
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved, there was an error in accessToken header.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).